# AForge shows error : "can't open the specified AVI file" when loading big size AVI file

Tags: c#, video, aforge, avi

I have developed a prototype to capture and replay the Video Files (*.avi). For this I am using **`AForge`** API. While recording the AVI file I have used **`WMV3`** compression. Problem is in the Video Replay module, when I am loading a big size AVI file, it is giving error **can't open the specified AVI file** on the following line :

```
_aviReader.Open(_videoFileName);
```

I have checked on internet a lot but did not find any solution yet. Any help or lead, to solve this problem, would be very appreciated.

**VideoReplay.cs**

```
private void OpenVideoSource()
{
    try
    {
         if (_aviReader != null)
         {
              _aviReader.Close();
         }

         if (_videoFileName != null)
         {
             _aviReader.Open(_videoFileName);  // At this line, I am getting Error "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in AForge.Video.VFW.dll" /*can't open the specified AVI file*/
             if (_aviReader == null)
             {
                 throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} failed to read video file.", _videoFileName), "playFile");
             }
             else
             {
                 _totalFrames = _aviReader.Length;
                 _frameRate = _aviReader.FrameRate;
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Logging Error
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills. I have added **OpenVideoSource()** method of my **VideoReplay.cs** class.

Comment: Could you share the video with us?

Comment: @mjwills, Problem is not with small video clips. I have tested this code with video files up to 1.7 GB video files. But when I loaded a 2.5 GB AVI file, it is kicking and giving error **can't open the specified AVI file**

Comment: I suppose by sharing the actual AVI file we can reproduce the issue. Just in case the problem is with the AVI itself...